# can't get select element id or name

Tags: jquery

The following code runs and returns the correct value for each select element except it does not get the id or name of the element. It always returns undefined.

```
$("#MainContent_Button3").click(function (event) {

        $(".quantities option:selected").each(function (i) {
            alert($(this).attr('id') + " : " + $(this).val());
        });

    $('#medications').trigger('close');
});
```

I've tried:

```
alert($(this).attr('name') + " : " + $(this).val());
alert(this.attr('id') + " : " + $(this).val());
alert($(this).attr('id') + " : " + $(this).val());
alert($(this).prop('id') + " : " + $(this).val());
alert(this.id + " : " + $(this).val());
alert(i.id + " : " + $(this).val());
```

Here is the HTML

```
<select id="ddl1" name="ddl3" class="quantities">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
                <option>6</option>
                <option>7</option>
                <option>8</option>
                <option>9</option>
                <option>10</option>
                <option>11</option>
                <option>12</option>
                <option>13</option>
                <option>14</option>
                <option>15</option>
                <option>16</option>
                <option>17</option>
                <option>18</option>
                <option>19</option>
                <option>20</option>
            </select>
```

Comment: Have you specified `id` of `option`?

Comment: `$(this)` would be the option - you want `$(this).parent().attr('id')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to find the closest parent `select` tag to get the `select` of current `option`. The key word this in each represents `option` not `select`.

```
alert($(this).closest('select').attr('id') + " : " + $(this).closest('select').val());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".quantities option:selected") //-- Returns the option element
```

You need the select element which is actually the parent so try like below,

```
 $(".quantities option:selected").each(function (i) {
     var $parent = $(this).parent();
     alert($parent.attr('id') + " : " + $parent.val());
 });
```

I am assuming you have more code to work with `option` element, if not iterate over the `$('.quantities')` so that `this` will be `select` and not `option` element.